# Rails - has_many :through - Create new record and association in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, has-many-through, form-for, fields-for

I am currently struggling with a has_many :through association in my project. The basics of the association are as follows:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contents
    has_many :topics, :through => :contents
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contents
    has_many :courses, :through => :contents
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :courses
    belongs_to :topics
end
```

probably could not be more basic..

So the idea is that a user can create many courses, and also create many topics. Topics are associated with courses via the Content class. Doing it this way means a user could create a number of topics and associate them with a number of courses. Great, saves the user typing out the lot again when course topics overlap. This is all fine and dandy.

However, I want the user to first create a Course and then from there create a number of new topics for that course. Seems logical to me.

My issue is I am struggling to get my head around the best way to do this?

I could scrap the :through association and have a basic topic belongs_to course association as this would do what i want but at the expense of the extra functionality I want.

I am thinking along the lines of a form_for Topic with fields_for content? I can't help thinking this is a common problem with a common answer but cant find the answer on the interweb. Maybe its my wording. Hope this make complete sense to someone....?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, so for clarification, you mean you would like to be able to create a `Course` AND one or more associated `Topic` objects simultaneously?

Comment: yes, thats sounds something like it. Sorry for the ambiguity but its really confusing me. So basically, after a course is created, in its show page there would a link like "Add Topic" which would go through creating a new `Topic` and create the record in `contents` aswell to make the association. The topics relating to the course will be shown in a list on the course `show` page. Much like a basic `belongs_to` association but with the the trimmings. Hopefully this is making sense. Newish to Rails but fast learner.

Comment: The main purpose being to have the `Topic` associated with more than one `Course` but be able to build as if it belongs to the `Course`. I think that makes sense....

Comment: Oh ok, so creating a new `Topic` for a specific course is on a *separate* page then (the course's show page). Meaning, its not created at the exact same moment the `Course` is created. Alright, that's fairly easy, in fact. Answer forthcoming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll write this from a somewhat general perspective (but using the models you described), because it is not just relevant to the situation you described, but relevant to any time you're creating a new association in a Many-to-Many relationship using `has_many :through`.

In rails, here is a simple example to create a new `Topic` object, which is associated with a `course`:

```
@course.topics << Topic.new(params[:topic])
```

The above assumes you have previously already loaded up your `Course` object and stored it in `@course`. It also assume that the `Topic` data is coming from a form, and stored in the parameter map under the `:topic` key.

If you examine your log when this portion executes, because you set up your associations correctly, you should see **two** insert statements: `INSERT INTO "topics"...` and `INSERT INTO "contents"...`.

There are other ways (some far more roundabout than others) to do this, but I believe this is the most straightforward.

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Great! thanks for this, Teeg. I will play around with this and see how is comes out. Would be interested to see any tutorials or an API that relates to the code you have specified so I get a better understanding. A little unsure where I put this code at the moment but  hopefully all will become clear. Thanks

Comment: @user3267045 that piece of code would go in your controller, in whatever action is supposed to respond to the creation of a new `Topic`. I kept it barebones like that because I didn't want to make any assumptions about how your system looked / worked (and risk causing confusion). It's also hard to say more without seeing how the form that creates the new `Topic` is supposed to work. If you want to post that (or your idea for that), I can try and take a look.

Comment: Thanks, Teeg. I have something working now. Looks a little different to the create methods I've seen before for example `@topic = @course.toics.new(topic_params)` and `if @topic.save` etc, just the code you specified without checking `.save`. Sound correct? works fine so Im happy.

Comment: @user3267045 Yup, that also looks correct! I don't think there is any significant difference between the way I did it, and what you just showed me (and if there is, its minute). And if you haven't observed any ill effect, you're good to go. Best of luck, and if you wouldn't mind (unless you need something else), do you want to upvote and accept (green checkmark to the left)  this answer if you feel it helped you?

Comment: Answer accepted :) can't upvote I'm afraid as I'm a massive noob! 15 reputation required. When I'm more respectable I will come back and do it!! Thanks for your help!